# Overriding Doctrine enum default getter

Tags: symfony1, enums, doctrine, symfony-1.4

In base class:

> @method enum getWeightType() Returns the current record's
>   "weight_type" value

Subclass:

```
class Exercise extends BaseExercise
{
    public function getWeightType() 
    {
        $type = parent::getWeightType();
        if ($type == 'free') {
            return 'Wolny';
        } else {
            return 'Stacjonarny';
        }
    }
}
```

so basically I want to ouput values other than stores in database.

In indexSuccess:

```
echo $exercise->getWeightType()
```

I am getting error:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

Could somebody give me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the protected method when overriding:

`$type = $this->_get('weight_type');`

Otherwise youre jsut going to run yourself in circles because its going to keep trying to call accessor method youre overriding never getting to a method that actually gets the internal value.